# How to get Video Performance Report from youtube API

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

i am following this 2 links
the report i need to get is [Video Performance Report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/video-performance-report)   ,and  [CreateReportingJob](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/code_samples/java)  which has an example showing how to `CreateReportingJob`
but there are many reports i could make with this API how could i "tell"
YouTube to get this specific report(Video Performance) ?